# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {array}

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is the script I'm using.

```
<script>
var user_lat, user_lng;
var map;
var url = "./rest/network";
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 17,
      lng: 80
    },
    zoom: 5
  });
    $.post(url,function(data,successStatus){
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
              position: value,
              draggable: false,
              map: map,
              title: "cab"
            });
        });
    });     
}
</script>
```

The url returns `[{lat:12.74711089,lng:79.98483278},{lat:18.0,lng:80.0},{lat:19.0,lng:78.0}]`

Again when I use this code its working

```
<script>
var user_lat, user_lng;
var map;
var url = "./rest/network";
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 17,
      lng: 80
    },
    zoom: 5
  });
    var data = [{lat:12.74711089,lng:79.98483278},
                {lat:18.0,lng:80.0},
                {lat:19.0,lng:78.0}];
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: value,
          draggable: false,
          map: map,
          title: "cab"
        });
    });

}
</script>
```

If the array format is the problem, then the second code also shouldn't work. But it is working. I'm not knowing the reason behind the problem. Is there any problem with the ajax call?

Comment: `data` is not array, it's a string. Use `data = JSON.parse(data);` before `each` in response callback. Let me know if this works.

Comment: when I use that it is telling me anonymous function at the line `data = JSON.parse(data)` and error is `unexpected token at line 1` which is <!DOCTYPE html>. Is it the problem of the array format?

Comment: You should make sure that JSON files are sent with the right header and _only_ contain JSON data. If you want to import structured data (like XML), you will have to do a different conversion.

Comment: okay. I'm directly returning String from my java web service. Now I changed the String format. Added double quotes to the key in the key-value pair. And then parsed using JSON.parse(data). Now its working. But really my knowledge in sending response from the service is less. Every comment is really helpful for me. Thankyou. @somethinghere

Comment: Thankyou. It is solved @Tushar

Comment: As long as your content header is `Content-Type:application/json` then it should read fine (as long as its a properly formatted JSON string). But hey, good that this worked!

Comment: @somethinghere  thanks for that. Can you provide me any link providing knowledge on how data is transferred in application/json or  application/xml and all about content headers.

Comment: Thats very much related to what language you use in your server. If its PHP, this will work: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - But if you are not in control, have a look at jQuery's ajax contentType declaration - it will read the correct info for you. Just google it, its pretty commonplace :) good luck!

Comment: @somethinghere. Thank-you. It's really helpful. I'm a java programmer. Now I'm planning to learn php. Don't know how easy or difficult it is. But really looking forward to learn it. How recommended it is to learn php. Scala, python are in my list then.

Comment: PHP practically owns the web (apart from all the HTML, but thats your view, PHP would be your Model and Controller). Its a good language to get started in and it's used for an immense amount of things around the web. If you want to learn whats hot in PHP, Laravel is a pretty good framework from what I'v heard (tried using it myself but it was to big for my needs)